# set operations using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, set, operations

I need to implement a set of functions providing various set operations such as create set, add element to set, etc. I am new to programming, however, I know how to write a function but my problem with this task is that I need to use pointers and I have no idea how to for example write a function to create a set with pointers. I am not asking for solutions, just a good explanation to get me started! Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this: http://bit.ly/H5jb6Q

Comment: I did I understood pointers but I don't know how to use them on sets if you read my question properly you would have understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets can be stored in various data structures such as, but not limited to, a linked list. You then need to abstract away set operations to add, remove, test for membership of elements. I advise you to read data structure related literature and do some related exercises before undertaking this small project.

Comment: Thanks. If I use a linked list I still have to user pointers?

Comment: Yes. See http://www.gatesit.org/gitdownloads/C&DS.pdf for one of the tutorials I found. Note that a linked list is but a means to contain your data. You can alternatively use a fixed array that you will need to "resize" as needed when the array space is exhausted. This could be an alternative to writing linked list code.

Comment: Thanks a lotttttt for your help :) I am using pointers. I have this prototype setelement* add(int elem); but in my source file I did void add. What should be the return type of add in the source file in this case?

Comment: I have this method for creating the linked list:

struct set_el* create(int value)
{
    struct set_el *ptr = (struct set_el*)malloc(sizeof(struct set_el));
    if(NULL == ptr)
    {
        printf("\n Node creation failed \n");
        return NULL;
    }
    ptr->value = value;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    head = curr = ptr;
    return ptr;
}

The value is asked from the user in the main method however it is giving me an error unknown type set_el when I compile. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where did you declare set_el struct?

Answer (score 1):

First you need some structure to hold your pointers, it could be as simple as an array (or a linked list as Tarik suggested).

Once you have a structure you create the set functions.

E.g.

```
void createSet(int*** set, int maxsize)
{
  *set = malloc(sizeof(int*) * maxsize); 
}

void addPtrToSet(int** set, void* ptr, int* numberOfPointers)
{
  // check if pointer is already in array
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < *numberOfPointers; ++i)
  {
    if (ptr == set[i]) return; // already in set
  }
  set[(*numberOfPointers)++] = ptr;
}

...

const int maxsize = 10;
int** set = 0;
int a;
char* b;
int numberOfPointers = 0;
createSet(&set, maxsize);
addPtrToSet(set, &a, &numberOfPointers);
addPtrToSet(set, &b, &numberOfPointers);
addPtrToSet(set, &a, &numberOfPointers); // will not be added to set
```

here assuming `sizeof(int*) == sizeof(char*)`

Comment: +1 for your sample code. It would be nice to elaborate on what int*** is about, or maybe return the set via a return statement instead of the output parameter.

Comment: was on purpose to keep it a bit vague, I was thinking that being too detailed would not help, just showing an example to give a nudge in the right direction, there is of course much that can be done regarding error handling, performance etc.

Comment: It's just that I found int*** confusing for someone who is already not that fond of pointers.

Comment: the standard doesn't really specify a general size for pointers so therefore i choose int*. using void* may look better but in some cases since it is not an actual type it could cause trouble, i think the whole idea of having pointers in a set is a bit of constructed example, normally you know the type - just my 2c